# Mysql join 2 database and 3 tables query?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT      db1_t1.userid as userid
            , db1_t1.customer_id as vw_customer
            , db2_t1.customers_id as customer
            , db2_t1.orders_id as order
FROM        database1.table1 db1_t1
LEFT JOIN   database2.table1 db2_t1 
ON        db1_t1.customer_id = db2_t1.customers_id
```

It gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'order FROM
>   database1.table1 db1_t1 LEFT JOIN
>   database2.' at line 2

I am using php and mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a keyword - think `ORDER BY my_column`.

I'd suggest renaming it, but you could enclose it in backticks

```
db2_t1.orders_id AS `order`
```